# How to generate a list of palindromes with only 'x','y' and a given length n in Python?

Tags: python, palindrome

is there any patterns i can use to sort out how to create a string that is palindrome which made up with 'X' 'Y'

Comment: hint: I have some string of length n/2.  can that be used to construct a length n palindrome?

Comment: @IfLoop: Great comment, wish I saw it before I posted my answer. Would have made it a little more subtle. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Let's assume `n` is even. Generate every string of length `n/2` that consists of `x` and `y`, and append its mirror image to get a palindrome.

Exercise 1: prove that this generates *all* palindromes of length `n`.

Exercise 2: figure out what to do when `n` is odd.

Comment: when n is odd, just let the middle one be x or y, then append x/y to every string of length (n-1)/2 and its reverse version,is that right?

Comment: @user3426141: Yes (provided by "x or y" you mean "each of x and y").

Comment: dont know where to start to generate string, base case should be n=0 and 1?

Comment: @user3426141: There's many ways to do this: recursively; by generating integers between 0 and 2**n-1 and looking at their binary representation (0->x, 1->y); by using `itertools.product`; etc. Take your pick.

Comment: how to do it recursively? since string unlike list, it is immutatable

Comment: @user3426141 You can always use a list and make string out of it in the end, if that floats your boat better. But there's no need to, you can implement this in a totally purely functional way (no mutation)

Answer (score 0):

First generate all possible strings given a list of characters:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> characters = ['x','y']
>>> n = 5
>>> [''.join(i) for i in product(characters, repeat=n)]
['xxxxx', 'xxxxy', 'xxxyx', 'xxxyy', 'xxyxx', 'xxyxy', 'xxyyx', 'xxyyy', 'xyxxx', 'xyxxy', 'xyxyx', 'xyxyy', 'xyyxx', 'xyyxy', 'xyyyx', 'xyyyy', 'yxxxx', 'yxxxy', 'yxxyx', 'yxxyy', 'yxyxx', 'yxyxy', 'yxyyx', 'yxyyy', 'yyxxx', 'yyxxy', 'yyxyx', 'yyxyy', 'yyyxx', 'yyyxy', 'yyyyx', 'yyyyy']
```

Then filter out non-palindrome:

```
>>> n = 4
>>> [''.join(i) for i in product(characters, repeat=n) if i[:n/2] == i[::-1][:n/2]]
['xxxx', 'xyyx', 'yxxy', 'yyyy']
>>> n = 5
>>> [''.join(i) for i in product(characters, repeat=n) if i[:n/2] == i[::-1][:n/2]]
['xxxxx', 'xxyxx', 'xyxyx', 'xyyyx', 'yxxxy', 'yxyxy', 'yyxyy', 'yyyyy']
```

If you don't like if conditions in list comprehension, you can use `filter()`:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> characters = ['x','y']
>>> n = 5
>>> def ispalindrome(x): return x[:n/2] == x[::-1][:n/2];
>>> filter(ispalindrome, [''.join(i) for i in product(characters, repeat=n)])
['xxxxx', 'xxyxx', 'xyxyx', 'xyyyx', 'yxxxy', 'yxyxy', 'yyxyy', 'yyyyy']
```

Comment: I think your filter is wrong. At least `xyyxy` is not a palindrome

Comment: @NiklasB. thanks for catching that, forgot to reverse the sublist =)